# Average life span of a hurricane

Tags: weather-forecasting, extreme-weather

Wondering if there's data of what could be the average life span of an hurricane considering global warming as factor.

Comment: The problem with "average" lifespan is that, not all tropical storms become hurricanes.    If warmer oceans make a tropical storm into a short lived hurricane, even though the warmer oceans increased the Hurricane total (in this hypothetical) the average life span goes down.   A better measuring stick would be peak life span or how far East they begin, or how far North they stay Hurricanes or perhaps, changes in the Hurricane season (Atlantic, June 1 to Nov 30) or change in total output.  Average lifespan could give you information that works counter to what I think you're looking for.